# Can a DnD vampire or spawn use a mobile coffin?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, feats, movement

The Vampire Spawn monster class from DnD 3.5e *Libris Mortis* states under their Fast Healing that

> If reduced to 0 hit points in combat, it automatically
>   assumes gaseous form and attempts to escape. It must reach its
>   coffin home within 2 hours or be utterly destroyed. (It can travel
>   up to nine miles in 2 hours.) Once at rest in its coffin, it is helpless.
>   It regains 1 hit point after 1 hour, then is no longer helpless and
>   resumes healing at the rate of 2 hit points per round.

Similar wording is given in the Vampire entry in *Monster Manual I*.  The question is, must the coffin lie in a "home ground" for this to take place, or can the character load up their coffin in a cart and tote it to each location for easy access?  If so, then does this imply that destroying the coffin can keep a vampire dead?

Comment: I'm getting this horrible mental image from your title of a small cemetery on tank treads, and a little bobbly skull on the front gate...

Comment: Coffin in a Bag of Holding!

Comment: iirc, the description also states that vampires are "bound to the soil of their graves". It should be possible to have a vampire with a mobile coffin (with some quantity of soil), but I think the DM will have to build a good scenario around that idea, and not just use it as a "trick" to outwit his players, if that's what you had in mind.

Answer (score 5):

I think the most important thing to consider is just how "mobile" mobile is.  Sure you can pull a Vandread and lug a coffin with you, but then you have a coffin that can surely be whittled away it in less than an hour to get to your defenseless body.  So while a coffin on the move is possible due to the unstated RAW, where it is when you go back to it is vital.  Just how many places can you trust to see your wispy form go flying by and not capitalize on the opportunityto kill or imprison you?  So while mechanically this sounds like a great advantage (I'll move my coffin every four days between seven castles), who can you trust with your life to do this?

Additionally, almost every D&D campaign I've been in has taken some liberties on the more classical lore.  Your DM (assuming you're not it) might have different ideas as to just what a vampire's weaknesses and abilities should be.

Answer (score 5):

The only restriction is that the coffin must be “the vampire’s,” which may imply mere ownership, or it may imply that this is the coffin the vampire was originally buried in. That is up to the DM.

But a coffin can be moved, though they are typically large and heavy. A vampire is free to do so, or to have others do so. The primary problem with this is that it may be (dramatically) more difficult to secure a mobile coffin, and the vampire furthermore may require trustworthy henchmen to deal with the coffin while he’s in it, which could be a problem.

Comment: Hmm, at least D&D vampires (and spawn) have easy access to loyal henchmen, through their domination abilities.

Answer (score -3):

The first thing you have to understand is that even though vampires can make more vampires they don't build coffins! A vampire can create a vampire spawn by killing it with it's drain ability this dose not fabricate a coffin.

"If reduced to 0 hit points in combat, it automatically assumes gaseous form and attempts to escape. It must reach its coffin home within 2 hours or be utterly destroyed. (It can travel up to nine miles in 2 hours.) Once at rest in its coffin, it is helpless. It regains 1 hit point after 1 hour, then is no longer helpless and resumes healing at the rate of 2 hit points per round." This is the only rule on vampires around this stipulation cause their not meant for players to play they are story plot and villains.

As for your question yes you can have a mobile coffin the rules for this are found in other sources outside the regular DnD 3.5 but they convert effortlessly:

- The coffin must rest a single day with the vampire inside and out of sunlight for it to qualify as his/her coffin and then from that point on its the coffin that he/she must return to.
- A vampire who has no coffin can return to their grave(if they were buried) but not the room/place of death and rebirth that occurred to change them into a vampire.
- A vampire who has a coffin who wishes to travel must move his coffin to a new location and rest in it for a complete day and there must be no sunlight that can reach the coffin.
- Yes destroying the coffin of a vampire forces him to make a new one or suffer true death after his 2 hours of looking fail.

The sources for this come from too many books to list but they don't apply any stats or change based on other factors so they can fit any DnD 3.5 game.

Comment: Too many D&D books to list? Really? Can you give us a top 3?

Comment: As I said the books are not D&D they are out-sourced so they would have no factor of legitimacy; I simply use them to apply my own house rule on this item.

Comment: Please include your sources.

Comment: Interview with a Vampire, Dracula Bramstrokers, Let the Right one in; are the top 3 of my sources.